# Powershell - Organizer Email Address

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to retrieve the email address of the Organizer of a meeting in MS Exchange 2010, using Powershell.

```
(Get-Mailbox -Identity "John Doe").PrimarySmtpAddress
```

I get the below error

> The operation couldn't be performed because object 'John Doe' couldn't be found on 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

These are for meetings that have just been created, so how can the Organizer not exist?

Edit:

Here's the sequence of events:

- Fetch list of calendar events from exchange within specific date range
- Fetch email address of Organizer for each event <-- this is where I'm stuck

Full script:

```
$credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
$session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/PowerShell -Authentication kerberos -Credential $credential
Import-PSSession -Session $session -DisableNameChecking

#Date ranges
$exportDate = Get-Date -Format d
$startTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1) 
$endTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(+1)

$app = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$ns = $app.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$calFolder = 9
$calItems = $ns.GetDefaultFolder($calFolder).Items
$calItems.Sort("[Start]")
$calItems.IncludeRecurrences = $true
$dateRange = "[Start] >= '{0}' AND [End] <= '{1}'" -f $startTime.ToString("g"), $endTime.ToString("g")
$calExport = $calItems.Restrict($dateRange)

$exportFile = "D:\file.csv"
$calExport | select Subject, StartInStartTimeZone, EndInEndTimeZone, Duration, Organizer, RequiredAttendees, OptionalAttendees, Location | sort StartUTC -Descending | Export-Csv $exportFile
$exportData = Import-Csv $exportFile

foreach ($line in $exportData)
    {
        $emailAddress = $line.Organizer
        $emailAddress = (Get-Mailbox -Identity $line.Organizer).PrimarySmtpAddress
        $line | Add-Member -Membertype Noteproperty -Name OrganizerEmail -Value $emailAddress
        [array]$csvData += $line
        $emailAddress = $null
    }

Remove-PSSession $session
```

Please assist!

Comment: So for that to work the target mailbox has to have the AD attr of Name, Display Name or Alias of "John Doe". That does not appear to be the case. Can you find it using samaccountname or other acceptable attr for [`-Identitfy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps)

Comment: Perhaps its just a conceptual misunderstanding on my part - I've edited the original question above to clarify things a bit. Please read above

Comment: I suppose then you are holding more information to accurately answer the question. How are you getting events and how are you using those to try and get email addresses? Is the organizer a member of your organization.. .since it doesnt have to be. I feel that information is already in the event details.

Comment: The name `John Doe` may be ambiguous. Perhaps you can try an ambiguous name resolution search on the string "John Doe" using the [-Anr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mailboxes/get-mailbox?view=exchange-ps#parameters) parameter on the `Get-Mailbox` cmdlet?

Comment: Sorry about the delay guys - I've added the full script

Comment: As the others have said, use the AD account's Windows username, the mailbox alias, or the SMTP address as the Identity, not the displayname.

Comment: Yes! I got it working using the samaccountname filter on Get-ADUser. So to be fair, Matt has provided the correct answer, but I appreciate the help from everyone else too!

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I used to get the Organizers email address

```
 Get-ADUser -Filter {SamAccountName -like "*John Doe*"}
```